# Same amount of data makes index shuffle when sort in Datatables

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

I used [datatables](https://datatables.net/) for listing my post. I list my post via number of votes and sort it descending, the index is correct.

[image]

But when I sort it ascending, the index is getting shuffled. It was due to the cell having the same amount.

[image]

The lower index is shown first. Can view on the images I attached. Thanks for the help.

currently, this is the only jquery function I used. The first is to set the sorting at the top and the second is to sort the 7th column on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    otable = $('#dt').dataTable({
        "bSortCellsTop": true,
        "order": [[ 7, "desc" ]]
    });
 })
```

Comment: If you sort by votes then it's given that other columns will be shuffled.

Comment: its fine that the other column is shuffled, but i need the rank to be consistent with the number of votes. when number of votes is ascending, then the rank will be in descending order, and vise versa

Comment: I don't think there's solution for that in this instance, Unless  "serverSide" is set to true in your datatables settings and your data comes dynamically from a remote file.

Comment: Hi @KarloKokkak, I finally got it work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add an [orderData](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) in my function.

Here's the code to get it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   otable = $('#dt').dataTable({
     "bSortCellsTop": true,
     "order": [[ 7, 'asc' ], [ 0, 'desc' ]],
     "columnDefs": [
         { "orderData": [ 0, 7],    "targets": 7 },
     ]
   });
})
```